# PaintComponent disrupting grid drawing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm new to Java as well as user interfaces, and I have a problem with Java Graphics. What I'm trying to achieve is drawing a grid on a JPanel, and then paint custom components into the grid.

Here is the class I want to draw the grid on (its base extends JPanel).

```
public class RectGridPanel extends GridPanel
{

    List<Rectangle> rects;  
    
    public RectGridPanel(Simulator sim)
    {
        super(sim);
        
        this.rects = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();        
        
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,20));
        
        for(int x = 1; x < 801; x += 40)
        {
            for(int y = 2; y < 801; y += 40)
            {
                Cell newCell = new RectCell(x, y, sim);
                this.add(newCell);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        for(int x = 1; x < 801; x += 40)
        {
            for(int y = 2; y < 801; y += 40)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 40, 40);
                g2.draw(rect);
                rects.add(rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the cells I want to draw inside the grid:

```
public class RectCell extends Cell
{
    Rectangle shape;
    
    public RectCell(int x, int y, Simulator sim)
    {
        super(x, y, sim);
        shape = new Rectangle(x, y, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(shape);
    }
}
```

So the grid on its own draws out fine, but as soon as I try to create cells inside it it gets disrupted like that: [image]

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: What are `Cell` and `GridPanel`?

Comment: `rects.add(rect);` This will add all rectangles to a list every time `paintComponent()` is called. You should only initialize the list once on creation instead.

Comment: You should have one drawing `JPanel` that's responsible for all drawings.  You maintain the state of the board with a logical model consisting of one or more Java getter/setter classes.  The drawing `JPanel` reads the game state from the logical model and draws the game board accordingly.  You have to draw everything in each and every frame of your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RectCell extends Cell
{
    Rectangle shape;
    
    public RectCell(int x, int y, Simulator sim)
    {
        super(x, y, sim);
        shape = new Rectangle(x, y, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(shape);
    }
}
```

The `Graphics` object that is passed to this `paintComponent()` function defines the screen space where the current `RectCell` can draw. The coordinate sysetem is relative to the upper left corner of the `RectCell`, so drawing the background should always start at `x = 0` and `y = 0` or some other meaningful value. The coordinates here are not relative to the parent component as you seem to assume.

Better yet, set the background color and let Swing take care of painting it rather than painting a rectangle yourself.

Comment: I tried doing it with background color now, a drew the grid using JPanels and giving them a border, then adding them to the gridlayout i created in RectGridPanel. And again the grid works just fine, but after I put cells on the newly created JPanel it gets weird, the cells get smaller in size the further away they are from the top left corner (though i guess it's only their backgrounds since the mouse listener attached to them works correctly).

Comment: @HairyGnome It sounds like you have changed your code significantly since you first posted this question. I suggest posting a new question if you still need help. Be sure to include enough code so that we can compile and run it ourselves, but leave out any code that isn't relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you try to achive.
What is the reason for RectCell? Why not paint the shapes direct in the RectGridPanel?
The nested loop in the paintComponent it not a good idea. Be aware that the paintComponent is called very often and every time you in crease the rects list with new objects. The former painted rectangles get lost (qraphicaly) and new rectangles with the same parameters are blowing the list.

Comment: A component to represent each cell is just fine. What you suggest is the same as why not paint all of your buttons and labels in one `paintComponet()`. We create classes to represent the objects in our programs.

Comment: Yes, you are right with components you can make the super.paintC... render them. But then you have to use a Layout and define the different width and height attributes of the component so that the LayoutManager knows how to render.

Comment: That might be the problem here: `Cell` doesn't play nicely with the LayoutManager API.

Comment: I see a GridLayout is used. But then the x/ypositioning  of the shape inside RectCell makes no sense. The positioning of each RectCell is managed by the GridLayout, if the shape in the RectCell is necessary its x and y should be static. With increasing the values for each instanciation you make the shape move out of the painting area of the component.

Comment: Yup, I just noticed the same thing and started writing an answer along those lines. One issue is that the coordinate system of the `Graphics` object passed to `RectCell.paintComponent()` defines the area that object can paint on. It isn't the area for the parent `RectGridPanel`.